# Yii framework custom 403 handling for specific controller

Tags: yii

I have a requirement that checks if the current loged in user is a payed member or not for a set of action. if the user in not a payed member then he has to be sent to the take membership page. following is the code. In the controller (Yii framework )

```
public function accessRules()
{  return array(

        array('allow', 
            'actions'=>array('enroll','index','admin','suggesttags'),
            'users'=>array('@'),
            ),
        array('allow', 
            'actions'=>array('view', 'read'),
            'users'=>array(Yii::app()->user->name),
            'expression' => 'Yii::app()->controller->hasPaied()'
            ),
```

now the `hasPayed()` functions returns false for unpaid member and at present user is redirected to 403 exception.

I want to customize the 403 exception page to 'take membership' page. Is there a way to do it? so that all the exception raised from this specific `controller\action` are send to the take membership page and rest 403 exception remain unchanged ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using **deniedCallback** from [CAccessControlerFilter](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CAccessControlFilter).

```
// optional, the denied method callback name, that will be called once the
// access is denied, instead of showing the customized error message. It can also be
// a valid PHP callback, including class method name (array(ClassName/Object, MethodName)),
// or anonymous function (PHP 5.3.0+). The function/method signature should be as follows:
// function foo($user, $rule) { ... }
// where $user is the current application user object and $rule is this access rule.
// This option is available since version 1.1.11.
'deniedCallback'=>'redirectToDeniedMethod',
```